# Subset of a matrix as.numeric in R for log2

Tags: r, numeric

I have a data matrix (`data`) of 54675 obs. of 170 variables. And I want to perform

```
data.matrix.2 <- log2(data[,9:ncol(data)])
```

i.e. for values from the 9th column and beyond. The 8 columns before that are characters. I get the following error

```
Error in Math.data.frame(data.matrix[, 9:ncol(data)]) : 
  non-numeric variable in data frame:
```

Is there a way to treat a subset of the matrix as.numeric for the the log transform.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was that you had gotten a character matrix and needed:

```
as.numeric(data.matrix.2[ , -(1:8) ])
```

... but data.matrix() should coerce to 'numeric' mode. Oh, no, there you go. You weren't using the data.matrix function .... so it would be better not to use the name "data.matrix" since that is also the name of an R function.

You are properly using "[,]" so your assumptions about your data object are probably flawed. There must be a column of data that got created as factor or character in the remaining 162 columns. You need to run str(data.matrix) to see which one(s) it/they are.

Comment: or `which(!sapply(data.matrix.2,is.numeric))`